# Auto arrange of list items like table columns (Book glossary style)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to have an alphabetical list.

**The catch:**

1. List item will have a fixed width
2. List will have a fixed height.
3. Items should start from top after the specified height

**Please check the image for reference.:**
[image]

**[What i got yet](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/JABrp/)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would be nice if you could at least provide some code.

Comment: @PhilippBraun i want same as book's glossary. I posted the code as jsfiddle link.

Comment: here is a nice link http://rickbjarnason.com/creating-multi-column-lists-using-css/ which might help you!

Comment: @PhilippBraun Thanks! but it is similar to list a part post http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/. Its not helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired behavior quite easily using **CSS3** columns. Here's a sample on how to do it.

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /*3 is just a placeholder -- can be anything*/
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    width: 300px; /*your fixed width*/
    height: 100px; /*your fixed height*/
}
```

**Result**:
[image: Result]

**Jquery Alternative:**
An awesome plugin by Taylor Smith [Jquery column sort](https://github.com/taylorsmith/jquery-column-sort)

I hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: Great! it works! +1 for this & i am editing your answer as i used an jquery plugin alternative.